# apple archive errors

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to uploading my app to apple through archive in xcode but i'm having these issues:

1)iPhone/iPod touch: Info.plist: unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found. You must define CFBundleIcons, CFBundleIconsFiles, CFBundleIconFile, or provide a default Icon.png that is 57x57

2) unable to extract code signing entitlements from you application. please make sure myappname-prefix.pchmynameapp is a valid match executable that's properly code signed.

i dragged in the boxes the 2 icons and the screenshots (retina and not) but i don't know how to resolve it. Also the other issues i don't know how to resolve them.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify your Icon.png and Icon@2x.png in your plist.

Comment: and what dimensions must they have?

Comment: Icon.png must be 57*57 and Icon@2x.png must be 114*114.Also the bundle identifier mustbe same as in the profile that u created in your developer account.

Answer (score 0):

1st one is that either you have not set the icon for your app or the icon specified is not in the given format. see here detail about icon

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html

the 2nd one is that your profile is not matching with your app. i.e your bunndle identifier is not matching with your specified app name in provisioning profile. see this link for detail

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html

Comment: the bundle identifier in xcode and the bundle identifier in the distribution profile are the same. what is the problem?